How to plot two images of same shape in a plot, with one colorbar and still getting the images to be the same size?
I am trying to plot two satellite images next to eachother. The images is of the same area and have the same shape. One image is true color, and the other i have performed my analysis on. I want the images to appear the same size in the plot, as it is easier to compare. However, i only want the colorbar for the one where i have performed my analysis to be included. The image shape is 300*300 if that matters. And i want a nice plot where both images have the same height Y, width X.
This is how i usually plot:
            plt.figure(figsize = (20,15))
            plt.subplot(121)
            plt.imshow(rgb_img)
            plt.axis("Off")
            plt.subplot(122)
            plt.imshow(analysis)
            plt.colorbar()
            plt.axis("Off")
            plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1)  # Adjust the horizontal space between subplots
            plt.show()



And i would prefer to just add something so that this happens automatically.
The closest i got was:
           fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 30))
            gs = GridSpec(1,7)
            
            # Define the first subplot to take up one part
            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:3])
            ax1.imshow(rgb_img)
            ax1.axis("off")
            
            # Define the second subplot to take up two parts
            ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 3:6])
            im = ax2.imshow(analysis)
            ax2.axis("off")
            
            cax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,6: ])
            fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
           
            plt.show()

However, i am still not happy about the ratio of colorbar to the images, and it is frustrating to change the ratios manually.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have you considered using Constrained Layout? https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html#colorbars

I did not know it was an option. It works now, thank you!
